# gz-file generated programatically in C# differs from on generated manually

Tags: c#, filestream, memorystream, gzip, gzipstream

I'm doing an analysis of a filevault belonging to an application which gz-compress and adds a custom header to every file uploaded to it.

The header is ASCII-text consisting of header start element, containing a sha-1 checksum of the compressed file and the length of the decompressed file before the end-of-header element.

I can decompress the file just fine manually by removing the header (usually around ~65 bytes), saving the file and then decompressing it with 7-zip, gunzip and similar tools. If I check the hash of the resulting gz-file and the length of the decompressed file everything matches the expected hash and length stored in the header.

If I do the same operation programatically, I get weird results. I would expect that the gz-file and the decompressed file would have the same hash and length as the manually decompressed files, but this is not the case. The gz-file resulting from the code below is around ~700 bytes larger than the manually processed file, and needless to say the hashes doesn't match. The decompressed file (an image) is visually identical with the manually decompressed file, and has the exact same length, but gives a different hash value.

Opening the two gz-files in 7-zip shows me the following:
[image: Manually processed file on the left, programatically processed file on the right.]

The left file is the gz-file I processed manually. The right one was done programatically, and claims that the (very same) image is 2,4GB. Am I doing something horribly wrong somewhere, or is this 'as-designed'?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string TempDir = @"c:\temp\so\";

    string file = "../../../SampleFiles/SPO_6c5af66f-0a8b-4b27-848b-7e19346ee6c7.jpg";
    FileInfo myFile = new FileInfo(file);

    List<byte> fileContents = new List<byte>();

    using (FileStream fs = myFile.OpenRead())
    {
        int bytesToRead = 1024;
        int fileLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);

        Byte[] tmpData = new Byte[bytesToRead];

        if (fileLength < bytesToRead) {
            bytesToRead = Convert.ToInt32(fileLength);
        }

        int numRead = fs.Read(tmpData, 0, bytesToRead);

        while (numRead > 0 || fileLength > 0)
        {
            fileContents.AddRange(tmpData);
            numRead = fs.Read(tmpData, 0, bytesToRead);

            fileLength -= bytesToRead;

            if (fileLength < bytesToRead)
            {
                bytesToRead = fileLength;
            }
        }

        var gzdata = fileContents.Skip(66).ToArray<byte>();

        var compressedStream = new MemoryStream(gzdata);
        var zipStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
        var resultStream = new MemoryStream();

        zipStream.CopyTo(resultStream);
        var resArray = resultStream.ToArray();

        compressedStream.Flush();

        File.WriteAllBytes(TempDir + "testfile.jpg.gz", gzdata);
        File.WriteAllBytes(TempDir + "testfile.jpg", resultStream.ToArray());

    }
}
```

Comment: What is fileContents? You’re adding the tmpData into it regardless the amount of data you read into the buffer, so unless your file is exactly the multiple of the buffer size and every read gives full amount of data (neither is guaranteed) you’ll have differences.

Comment: I've modified the code a bit, so that it keeps count of how much of the file is left, only reading the exact length. Still the same issue.

Comment: You’re still adding to the unknown object just tmpData, not the part of it that was read. You can always try to read however much you want, but don’t ignore the return value when you process it.

Comment: Pretty unclear why you'd expect two different files to have the same size and hash.  You need to go back to the code that saved the testfile.jpg.  It only has the .jpg extension but is not actually a JPEG file.  Common bug.

Comment: @HansPassant: The two files I mention are both based on the same original file. One is by manually removing the ASCII-header so that the resulting file starts with the proper GZ file signature (1F 8B 08) and then manually decompressing this file. 

The other file goes through the same process, only this is done programatically. The two gz-files should be identical as they are both a copy of the original file; the resulting images contained in the gz-files look identical, but the hash doesn't match.

Comment: @HansPassant 
If you have compressed archive and make a copy of this, you'd expect that both copies give you the same hash and size, and also that the extracted files are identical in terms of hash and size.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: fileContents is a list defined just before the using; tmpData reads data from the stream, this is then appended to the end of the list. Probably not the best way to do this I'm sure, but it should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: Sorry, somehow I missed that definition. And no, it shouldn’t if tmpData isn’t fully containing the data. It always adds 1024 bytes to the list even if you read one. So you’ll have to make sure you don’t add more. I also wouldn’t recommend using a list, a MemoryStream would work better directly and you could skip the 66 bytes first and then read the data.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll see if I can rewrite it. Thanks for the help, feel free to add it as an answer for a +1 from me! :)